# Clauses after non-accusative verbs or то

Tags: глаголы, предлоги, clauses, синтаксис

**1**. A friend of mine wrote `я не интересуюсь, кто с кем играет` (in a football match). Normally, **интересоваться** is followed by a word in the instrumental case. When the word is a noun, an adjective or a pronoun, there's no difficulty about declining it. But, in this context, **интересоваться** is followed by a completely new clause, which could be independent and not subordinate.

Maybe it's like **надеяться**? "Надеяться *на что*", but if we are hoping for something described by a whole clause rather than a noun, *на что* may be dropped. Like in `надеюсь, всё будет хорошо`, rather than `надеюсь на то, чтобы всё было хорошо`.

Anyway, is it a valid alternative to say `я не интересуюсь тем, кто с кем играет`?

I've previously noticed that a declined pronoun **то** may relate to an independent clause without any particular syntax connection.

Like this:

> путешествовать в этом году зависит **от того**, сколько денег
>   останется после ремонта чердака

**2**. The verb требовать normally is followed by genitive, but what if it is followed by a clause?

*They demanded me to rewrite the document.*

> Они потребовали (от меня) переписать документ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, it's absolutely valid and correct.

> путешествовать в этом году зависит от того, сколько денег останется
>   после ремонта чердака

The first clause is incorrect, unless you've omitted the beginning. In this case the infinitive cannot function as a subject by itself, we need a conventional subject in a form of a noun, eg.

> **Возможность** путешествовать в этом году зависит от того, сколько денег останется после ремонта чердака
>   or better still
>   **Возможность отправиться в путешествие** в этом году зависит от того, сколько денег останется после ремонта чердака

2. 

> *They demanded me to rewrite the document. - 
>   Они потребовали (от меня) переписать документ.*

You can append the subordinate clause with conjunction **чтобы** and provisionally with indicative pronoun **то** inflected in Genitive

> Они потребовали (от меня) (того), **чтобы** я переписа**л** документ.

Answer (score 2):

You'll get some pieces of textbooks yet, no doubt, but such constructions with words omitted but implied are possible, yes.

Not only those two verbs may be involved. It could be: "Я не знаю [того], кто с кем играет". Your examples: "я не интересуюсь [тем], кто с кем..."; "надеюсь [на то, что] все будет хорошо".

Now, the use of the verb "требовать" quoted by you is more like the use of modal verbs in English: "требовать сделать", "долженствовать быть" (that last one's rather poor example, but still possible).